# How to Display Categories in Select Box to Update the Record?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey Everyone Please help me, I want to update the record, but the problem is I can't see more than 1 categories in the select box. I have been using Php/MySQLi and Also Ajax.

**Total Categories Stored in the Database Three**

So, Please Look at that:

**Here is Php Function**

```html
function get_product_record()
       {
        global $con;
        $Pro_Update_Id = $_POST['Pro_Update_ID'];
        $query = "SELECT Product.Product_ID, categories.cat_name, categories.cat_id, product.Product_Name,product.Product_Qty,product.Price,product.Description from product INNER JOIN categories on product.Category_ID=categories.cat_id where product.Product_ID='$Pro_Update_Id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data = "";
            $data[0]=$row['Product_ID'];
            $data[1]=$row['cat_name'];
            $data[2]=$row['Product_Name'];
            $data[3]=$row['Product_Qty'];
            $data[4]=$row['Price'];
            $data[5]=$row['Description'];
            $data[6]=$row['cat_id'];
           
        }
            echo json_encode($data);
       }
```

**Here is jQuery File**

```html
function get_pro_record()
{
    $(document).on('click','#p_btn_edit',function()
    {
        var GetPID = $(this).attr('data-id');
        
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'includes/products/get_pro_record.php',
                method: 'post',
                data:{Pro_Update_ID:GetPID},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#product_id').val(data[0]);
                    $('#cat_up_name').html('<option id="p_update_id" value='+(data[6])+'>'+(data[1])+'<option>');
                    $('#product_up_name').val(data[2]);
                    $('#up_Qty').val(data[3]);
                    $('#up_Price').val(data[4]);
                    $('#up_description').val(data[5]);
                    $('#products_update').modal('show');
                }
            })
    })
}
```

Here is a Screenshot of the Project:
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of `data` from your ajax success and explain what your expectations are to what you are currently getting?

Comment: I'm getting data from Php function and Assign each database records in each input text fields and also Select Box. I've used JSON Encode Method to send data from Php to jquery File. Then I've used data and also Array Index to assign the data on the HTML fields.

Comment: you have declare $data = ""; as string and using it as array. Also you have initialized it in your while loop so each time it re-initialized. use $data = array(); out side of your while loop

Comment: I understand where the data is coming from but if you can give an example of that result it can make thing easier for myself and others to work with and debug for errors.

Comment: Dear, I followed this method, If you have another ideas or method, please tell me thanks.

Comment: Where is your Categories dropdown? is it one that showing Computer ?

Comment: Bro, I can't be getting another category from the database, I've gotten particular row record. If you are the user you want to change the category and then update the record, So How you can do that? You can't change the category bro, because inside dropdown has one category. I want to display all categories user will be able to change the category or another thing to update the record. Please help me I'm waiting for solution